# As Sigmoid function is non-linear, then how Logistic Regression works as a Linear Classifier?

Tags: regression, logistic

I am very confused about the question: As Sigmoid function is non-linear, then how Logistic Regression works as a Linear Classifier? Can anybody please help?

Comment: Does it help you to write the logistic regression as $\log\left(\dfrac
{\hat p}
{1 - \hat p}
\right) = X\hat\beta
?$

Comment: See the [linear-model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/linear-model/info) tag info: a linear model is linear in the coefficients of the predictors. Even the predictors can be involved in nonlinear transformations. There can be a non-linear mapping from the resulting linear predictor to the outcome. The [linear predictor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_predictor_function) and [generalized linear model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model) entries in Wikipedia provide more details.

Comment: @Dave's point is that nonlinear functions can have linear contour lines (level sets).  In general, when a function is of the form $f(\beta)=g(X\beta)$ for *any* function $g,$ then the level sets $f^{-1}(y)$ are all parallel linear subspaces (or unions of them).